# Does the compiler do validation for valid escape characters in string literal

Tags: c#, string

The compiler for normal **string literal** with valid `escape sequence` like `\n`,`\t` compiles without any error.

But the moment I use `invalid escape characters` like `\s`,`\w` the compiler shows an error.Yes,We can avoid the error by using `verbatim string` or escaping it with `\\` but my question is

Do compiler **validates** the string literals for valid `escape characters` and if so is that it's only purpose!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do compiler validates the string literals for valid escape characters

Yes, it obviously does, that’s why you get the error messages.

> and if so is that it's only purpose!

I don’t really understand this question. I am assuming you are wondering why the compiler doesn’t simply accept invalid escape sequences and treats them verbatim. This would indeed be a possibility but it would render the interpretation of string literals slightly inconsistent: `\x` would mean different things depending on the actual value of `x`.

At the very least, there’s no disadvantage in C#’s strict checking of escape sequence validity. And maybe it avoids errors due to typos and confusions arising from different numbers of consecutive backslashes.

Comment: hmm..great..i forgot the strict type checking of c#..but then hey had to bring in verbatim strings to silence that very purpose..anyway thx..

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It No, verbatim strings don’t “silence” anything. They simply offer a *distinct* syntax to create string literals (and notably there are no escape sequences in verbatim strings, you can only escape the quote itself by doubling it: `""`).

Answer (score 2):

Yes compiler validates the string and if you use an invalid escape character you will get error:

[Compiler Error CS1009 - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44ezxxy3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> An unexpected character follows a backslash `(\)`in a string. The
>   compiler expects one of the valid escape characters. For more
>   information, see [Character Escapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e.aspx).